# rsync fails to work with -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no option

Tags: linux, rsync, directory, solaris, hostname

Below rsync works and helps copy remote directory to localhost

```
/bin/rsync -rv myremoteuser@myremotehost:/tmp/Deployments/ /web/playbooks/automation/getfiles/tmpfiles/4/E5EA787E/myremotehost/
```

Once i add `-o  StrictHostKeyChecking=no` it fails with the below error:

```
/bin/rsync -rv -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no myremoteuser@myremotehost:/tmp/Deployments /web/playbooks/automation/getfiles/tmpfiles/4/E5EA787E/myremotehost/
Unexpected remote arg: myremoteuser@myremotehost:/tmp/Deployments
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1348) [sender=3.1.2]
```

I want it to work and also work when i put it under double quotes like below:

```
"/bin/rsync -rv -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no myremoteuser@myremotehost:/tmp/Deployments /web/playbooks/automation/getfiles/tmpfiles/4/E5EA787E/myremotehost/"
bash: /bin/rsync -rv -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no myremoteuser@myremotehost:/tmp/Deployments /web/playbooks/automation/getfiles/tmpfiles/4/E5EA787E/myremotehost/: No such file or directory
```

Below are the details:

```
$ /bin/rsync --version
rsync  version 3.1.2  protocol version 31
Copyright (C) 1996-2015 by Andrew Tridgell, Wayne Davison, and others.
Web site: http://rsync.samba.org/
Capabilities:
    64-bit files, 64-bit inums, 64-bit timestamps, 64-bit long ints,
    socketpairs, hardlinks, symlinks, IPv6, batchfiles, inplace,
    append, ACLs, xattrs, iconv, symtimes, prealloc

rsync comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.  This is free software, and you
are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.  See the GNU
General Public Licence for details.
[mylocaluser@mylocalhost myremotehost]$ uname -a
Linux mylocalhost 3.10.0-1160.76.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jul 26 14:15:37 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: putting the entire command in double quotes means that the entire command should be treated as the name of the executable program to execute.  that is not at all what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rsync doesn't take ssh `-o` options on its command line.  You have to put ssh options into an ssh command string you pass to rsync's `-e` option.  Something like:

```
/bin/rsync -rv -e 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' myremoteuser@myremotehost:/tmp/Deployments /web/playbooks/automation/getfiles/tmpfiles/4/E5EA787E/myremotehost/
```

You should be able to wrap the above in double-quotes as you mentioned, since the `-e` argument is in single quotes.  The man page also mentions using the `RSYNC_RSH` environment variable as an alternative to the `-e` command-line option.